# Logging users of a Cisco Pix 501

Tags: firewall, logging

We are in the process of migrating away from a Cisco PiX 501 to another firewall.

As a result, we have a different IP address for our default gateway. Most machines on the network are moving over to the new firewall as they reboot and use DHCP to configure themselves. However, a few machines has their IP and gateway addresses statically configured, and as a result, are still using the old firewall.

So far, we have found 5 machines that had problems when we temporarily turned off the PiX. This was done the hard way (our DNS system went down until we figured it out), and I would prefer to avoid embarrassing myself any more.

Is there anyway to confgure the PiX to log the IP addresses of any machines that are still using it as the IP gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this that I know of.

However, you could catch the syslogs that the pix is spewing out, to see what IPs are still using it for access.

You could also just bite the bullet and turn off the pix and configure the people that come running to you because they can't snipe their auction on eBay.

For future reference, you really should devise some scheme for keeping track of statically mapped addresses...